# Is it possible to use quote macros from syntex?

Tags: rust, macros

I am implementing a macro using [this sample](https://github.com/serde-rs/syntex/blob/master/hello_world/hello_world_macros/src/lib.rs) as basis. I now want to use `quote_expr!` in the macro expansion code:

```
fn expand_macro<'cx>(
    cx: &'cx mut ExtCtxt,
    sp: Span,
    _: &[TokenTree]
) -> Box<MacResult + 'cx> {
    let expr = quote_expr!(cx, { const A: u32 = 10; });
    MacEager::expr(expr)
}
```

The compiler errors because `quote_expr!` is not defined.

I found that `quote_expr!` is defined in [base.rs](https://github.com/serde-rs/syntex/blob/master/syntex_syntax/src/ext/base.rs) via a mechanism similar to my `expand_macro` function.

My main crate has a `build.rs` that generates `main.rs` from `src/main.rs.in` by expanding macros. I have a `expand_macro` function in the second crate which uses the `build.rs` from main crate.

To use `quote_expr!` should I have three crates, two of them with `build.rs`?

Is there a simpler way to just write an expression, maybe by putting it in a string and calling the parser to produce a token tree?